# How do I remove a large file from an unsynced commit when that commit is 5+ commits ago?

Tags: git, commit

As with all Git questions, I'm sure this has been answered a dozen times before, but I haven't been able to find my special snowflake twin, so thanks for the patience.

Here's the rub: 5 commits ago, I accidentally added a large file, around 500 megs, and didn't realize it. Now when I go to push to GitHub, I get an error about the 100meg limit and the push fails.

Most fixes to this concern the most recent commit- How do I tell git to just forget about that 500 meg file from 5 commits ago?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository